# How to search in two tables in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem regarding our RFID log in system project, if i only query one table (Student) it shows the data correctly but our system includes not only the log in of the students but also for the faculty and staff but when i put this query

```
With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT Firstname,IDnum FROM Students,Faculty WHERE RFID = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

    End With
```

it should show the data equal to the rfid if it is equal to either in the student table or faculty, i don't know what to do next please help

Comment: Before you do anything else, please, please, please read up on SQL injection and parameterized queries. This is a lawsuit waiting to happen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the table and column in the where clause. It looks like the `RFID` column is unique to one of the two tables.

Here's an example (assuming `RFID` belongs to the `students` table):

```
With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT Firstname,IDnum FROM Students s,Faculty f WHERE  '" & TextBox1.Text & "' in (f.<RFID Column Name>, s.RFID)"

End With
```

Another approach is to union the searches in your tables:

```
With cmd
     .Connection = cn
     .CommandText = _
         "SELECT Firstname,IDnum FROM Students s " + _
         "WHERE  '" & TextBox1.Text & "' = s.RFID " & _
         "UNION " + _
         "SELECT Firstname,IDnum FROM faculty f " + _
         "WHERE  '" & TextBox1.Text & "' = f.RFID "
End With
```

Comment: i dont get an error but even if i entered the correct id for the faculty it display another info from the students table

Comment: That looks like because the columns FirstName, IDNum are from the `students` table. You might consider doing a union of searches in the two tables. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Added alternative answer. If you have any other issues please update your post with concrete data model details (ie table definitions for students and faculty).

Comment: tnx! it works! but when i want to include an image to be displayed i get this error "The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable."

Comment: You would then need to join the unique `union` set to whatever contains the image data.

Comment: tnx i have fixed it!..what if i want to show a data that does not exist in the other table?